# Does the include order has any impact on covering indexes?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, covering-index

Is there any difference between the two following indexes in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON table_name (column_one, column_two)
   INCLUDE (account_id, id)
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON table_name (column_one, column_two)
   INCLUDE (id, account_id)
```

Comment: The order of the columns in your index (column_one, column_two) is *CRITICAL*.  The order of the columns in your (optional!) "INCLUDE" clause doesn't matter.  For an excellent discussion of the hows/whys, look here: [A Close Look at the Index Include Clause](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2019-04/include-columns-in-btree-indexes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference in behavior between these two indexes.  The order in the `INCLUDE` list does not matter.